# Spring+Hibernate selective merge two tables into one Entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I've got two relations in the MySQL whereas one is actually a child of the other:

```
Table A (id, prop1, ... , prop N)
Table B (id, id_A, prop N+1, ..., prop N+M)
```

Basically Table A has more or less only static values and Table B contains all dynamic values. There is the need to version all of the values of Table B.

However in the Java App I only need the latest version, eg.

```
select * from a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id_a
WHERE b.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM b WHERE propN+X = 42 GROUP BY id_a)
```

I would like to create only one Model/Entity for both relations. I'm using Spring 4.2.1 with Hibernate 5.0.2

I can't find a solution with SecondaryTable since I can't filter the Join:

```
@SecondaryTable(name = "table_b",
pkJoinColumns = {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id_a", referencedColumnName = "id")})
```

Is it possible to achieve this with a NamedQuery or a View in the DB? For me it seems that there is no way getting around creating two entity classes and one DAO to handle the data access. If so what would be the best approach to merge both entities (Embedding, One-To-Many)?